# I need someone to show me how to solve this input/output problem

Tags: functions, inverse

Alright, so I have:
$4y^3 = x$

And now I have to solve for $y$, where I can later use that equation to answer other questions I have. Can someone hint me out on how to solve for $y$ given the above formula?

Comment: Divide by four on both sides, and take cube root? That would give $y$ in terms of  $x$. Point is, your equation is already in terms of $x$, so how can you solve for it?

Comment: Sorry! I meant solve for y.

Comment: Ah! Then I've done just that, ain't I? $4y^3=x \implies y^3=\frac{x}{4} \implies y  = \sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{4}}$. That was my earlier hint, now I've given the answer. Besides, what are the other questions you need to solve?

Comment: That's what I arrived at as well. The problem is, the space allowed for the answer is y = ["BLANK"]^["BLANK"]. I was wondering if there was another way to write it in that format.

Comment: $y=\frac{x}{4}^\frac{1}{3}$. Your first blank would be $\frac{x}{4}$,and second $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. Remember the power rules all the time, they are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

community wiki answer so that the question can be closed

\begin{align*}
4y^3 & = x\\
y^3 & = \frac{x}{4}\\
y & = \left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align*}